# How to create index for sorting in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing, mongodb-query

I have requirement like I have a single field and I want to apply sorting on both direaction on same field like asc,desc. So how to create index for that field should I need to create separate index on same field with direaction or a single index will help for sorting of both direaction ?

I have check mongodb documentation but not found satisfied answer. They are suggesting to create compound index for that

```
{
  "timestamp":value
}
```

I have applied index something like

```
timestamp : -1,
timestamp : 1
```

Comment: Would be nice if you show same example code - what you already tried.

Comment: Where is the documentation where they suggest creating a compound index for the situation you described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to query and sort on the same field (`timestamp`),
   then you're good with either of
   `{ timestamp: -1 }` or `{ timestamp: 1 }` indexes, the direction (asc or desc) doesn't matter
2. But if you want to query on one field (let's say `someField`) but sort on other (`timestamp`),
   then yes, you need to add compound index `{ someField: 1, timestamp: 1 }`, the direction doesn't matter here too.
   Here are [MondoDB docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-on-multiple-fields) on sorting on multiple fields

After you add the indexes you can check if indexes indeed are used with your query running `explain` command, similar to this:

```
db.collection.find({ someField: 'hello' }).sort({ timestamp: -1 }).explain()
```